# getting exception from server in c# socket

Tags: c#

I have created a simple server and client program in c#. The server will send a string array to the client and the client will display it and the client will sent an id to server and the server will display it. My sample code is given below. When I run them, I get an exception in the server side. I have marked the line in which I am getting the exception.My sample code is given below:

server:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace server
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {  
        TcpListener tcpListener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 1234);
        tcpListener.Start();  
        while (true)
        {                     
            TcpClient tcpClient = tcpListener.AcceptTcpClient();
            byte[] data = new byte[1024];
            NetworkStream ns = tcpClient.GetStream();
            string[] arr1 = new string[] { "one", "two", "three" };
            var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(string[]));
            serializer.Serialize(tcpClient.GetStream(), arr1);
            tcpClient.Close();

              int recv = ns.Read(data, 0, data.Length); //getting exception in this line

            string id = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, recv);

            Console.WriteLine(id);

            }               
        }
    }
}
```

client :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

 namespace Client
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            byte[] data = new byte[1024];
            string stringData;

            TcpClient tcpClient = new TcpClient("127.0.0.1", 1234);
            NetworkStream ns = tcpClient.GetStream();             

            var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(string[]));
            var stringArr = (string[])serializer.Deserialize(tcpClient.GetStream());

            foreach (string s in stringArr)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(s);
            }

            string input = Console.ReadLine();
            ns.Write(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(input), 0, input.Length);
            ns.Flush();


        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.Write(e.Message);
        }

        Console.Read();
    }
}
}
```

The exception I am getting is:

```
   An unhandled exception of type 'System.ObjectDisposedException' occurred in System.dll 
   Additional information: Cannot access a disposed object.
```

Is there anything wrong in the code? What will I need to do to avoid this exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that in your server code you are closing the TCP client before you continue with reading the data. This is why you are getting the exception.

Also, you are trying to read 1024 bytes, but the client does not send 1024 (unless by an unlikely chance that the string that the client sends which is an input from the user is encoded into a 1024 byte array) so the server will simply block and do nothing because it is waiting for the client to send 1024 bytes.

One good way to manage reading and writing data from/to a stream is through the [BinaryReader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binaryreader%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [BinaryWriter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binarywriter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) classes.

Consider the following code to solve your issue (it contains some improvements to your code):

Server:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        TcpListener tcpListener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 1234);
        tcpListener.Start();
        while (true)
        {
            using (TcpClient tcpClient = tcpListener.AcceptTcpClient())
            {

                using (var network_stream = tcpClient.GetStream())
                {

                    using (BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(network_stream))
                    {
                        using (BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(network_stream))
                        {
                            string[] arr1 = new string[] { "one", "two", "three" };

                            writer.Write(arr1.Length);

                            foreach (var item in arr1)
                            {
                                writer.Write(item);
                            }


                            var id = reader.ReadString();

                            Console.WriteLine("Id: " + id);

                        }

                    }
                }

            }

        }
    }
}
```

Client:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            using (TcpClient tcpClient = new TcpClient("127.0.0.1", 1234))
            {
                using (NetworkStream network_stream = tcpClient.GetStream())
                {

                    using (BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(network_stream))
                    {
                        using (BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(network_stream))
                        {
                            int number_of_strings = reader.ReadInt32();

                            string[] lines = new string[number_of_strings];

                            for(int i = 0 ; i <  number_of_strings ; i++)
                            {
                                lines[i] = reader.ReadString(); //Store the strings if you want to

                                Console.WriteLine(lines[i]);

                            }

                            Console.WriteLine("Please input id:");

                            string id = Console.ReadLine();

                            writer.Write(id);

                        }

                    }

                }
            }

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.Write(e.Message);
        }

        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

Comment: An additional thing: If I add  StreamWriter sWriter = new StreamWriter(tcpClient.GetStream()); at the end of client and StreamReader reader1 = new StreamReader(tcpClient.GetStream());
at the end of server after the last line of your given code, i am getting an exception on the server at this line.  Actually I was trying to send a filename and file size from client to server,that's why added this line. Anything wrong here?@Yacoub Massad

Comment: I am not sure. I don't think that you should have two readers (`BinaryReader` and `StreamReader`). Why do you need to do this? Use `BinaryWriter` and `BinaryReader`. You can write/read the file size as an integer using such objects. Also, the `BinaryWriter` has an [overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143302(v=vs.110).aspx) that allows you to write byte[]. Use it to send the contents of the file. `BinaryReader` has a corresponding [overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143295(v=vs.110).aspx) that allows you to read binary data.

Answer (score 0):

tcpClient Implementing Idisposible interface it is better to call dispose method in tcpclient

```
tcpClient.Dispose();
```

else

```
tcpClient.GetStream().Close();
tcpClient.Close();
```

Closing the client does not close the stream.

```
 var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(string[]));
            serializer.Serialize(tcpClient.GetStream(), arr1);
            tcpClient.GetStream().Close()
            tcpClient.Close();
```

Comment: getting this error: 'System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient.Dispose(bool)' is inaccessible due to its protection level @Midhun Mundayadan

Answer (score 0):

You are using the `NetworkStream` after you have `Closed` the `TcpClient` (which disposed it). See updated while below:

```
while (true)
{                     
    var tcpClient = tcpListener.AcceptTcpClient();
    var data = new byte[1024];
    var arr1 = new string[] { "one", "two", "three" };

    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(string[]));
    serializer.Serialize(tcpClient.GetStream(), arr1);

    var ns = tcpClient.GetStream();
    var recv = ns.Read(data, 0, data.Length); //getting exception in this line

    var id = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, recv);

    Console.WriteLine(id);

    ns.Close();
    tcpClient.Close();
}
```

Comment: In that case I am not getting the string array output in console of client side @d.moncada

Comment: i am geting the same result. doesn't display the string array on client console @d.moncada

Comment: okay, I would have to look a bit more into it. but regarding your original question about getting an exception, I believe you now have this fixed. you should create a new question about your client issue.

Comment: yes but I need to display the string array on the client console @d.moncada

Comment: Right, which is a different issue than what your question states.